# How to keep the width of the Controls in the TableRow column

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I have a `tablerow` in which i put in a textview with `width==50dp`;But when i add another `tablerow` which contains a `textview` with `width==100dp`,then the first textview has to be stretched to 100dp.

How can keep the width of the first textview's width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use android:stretchColumns properties .
To Know more Check out [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this in layout for both textviews:

android:layout_width="0dp"

android:layout_weight="1"

This will give equal width to both the rows.